# How to get the max value out of a random list of numbers Python

Tags: python

I have this code I'm trying to get to work. I can create a set of random numbers, but I need to make the max value show up. I'm trying not to use python's built in max command, BUT, I will ask for an example if I can't find a solution.

```
import random
def randomNumbers(number):
    myList = []
    numbersToCreate = number
    while numbersToCreate > 0:
        randomNumber = int(random.random() * 100)
        myList.append(randomNumber)
        numbersToCreate = numbersToCreate -1
    return myList
```

One piece of code I've tried to enter is this:

```
theList = []
theList.sort()
biggest = theList [-1:][0]
print (theList)
```

When I try to run that with it I get an error telling me the list isn't defined. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's *nothing* in that list (in the snippet outside of the function)...of course it isn't well defined.

Answer (score 1):

```
theList = randomNumbers(30)
biggest = max(theList)
print (biggest)
```

Comment: Why are you sorting it first?

Comment: You use `max()`, which makes sorting redundant...but the use of `max` was undesirable.

Comment: @Soravux:- It was just an answer.OP asked how to use max.

Comment: I get an error telling me that max() arg is an empty sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution.

```
def randomNumbers(number):
    theList = []        
    numbersToCreate = number
    while numbersToCreate > 0:
        randomNumber = int(random.random() * 100)
        theList.append(randomNumber)
        numbersToCreate -= 1
    return theList

outList = randomNumbers(100)
outList.sort()
print outlist[-1] # No reason to slice the list, which is what you were doing.
```

Answer (score 1):

You really *should* use the [max()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#max) function of Python, at least for readability sake.

If not, you can always check how Python developers have implemented it in Python, since it is open source.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want int for your list, you can use `random.randint(min, max)` instead of `int(random.random()*100)`.
Second, you need to call your function and pass the return list to `theList`

```
def randomNumberList(n):
    theList = []
    for i in range(n):
        theList.append(random.randint(0,100))
    return theList

theRealList = randomNumberList(n)
```

Then you will be able to use the actual list.

```
theRealList.sort()
theBiggest = theRealList[-1]
```

Comment: This is slightly different from the OP's random number generation, as `int(random.random() * 100)` will [almost] never produce 100, but `random.randint(0, 100)` will produce 100 1/101th of the time.  It could very well be what the OP was looking for, though.  `randrange` is another possibility.

Comment: That's pretty close to what I'm looking for. I need to just get a random list of numbers, show them, and then the max value at the end.

Comment: @DSM I assumed that skipping integers isn't necessary in this case, so I didn't mention `random.randrange()`. And you are correct about 100, it should be `random.randint(0,99)`

Comment: Can't you replace your `randomNumberList` by `random_list = lambda n: [random.randint(0, 99) for i in range(n)]` ?